# Google auth: Problem with logging in after selecting my mail

Tags: authentication, gmail, localhost

[image]

I have problem with logging in after deploying my site to vercel. On site there is a cookie: (next-auth.callback-url    http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000). I think the cookie is problem of redirecting me to the wrong page. After i click and select my mail it redirects me to localhost page.

I tried changing everything

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]